# Page changed after refresh

Tags: angular, typescript

Im creating an Instagram Clone in angular 6 and Im facing a problem.
If I do a refresh in the page my home component, it is refreshed correctly displaying all my posts, but if I do a refresh on profile page, it automatically redirects me to home page instead of do the refresh and keep on profile page
[image: home]

After refresh it keeps working fine

Profile View
[image: Profile View]

After Refresh
[image]

app.routes

```
import {Routes} from '@angular/router'
import { AcessoComponent } from './acesso/acesso.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AutenticacaoGuard } from './autenticacao-guard.service';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile/profile.component';



export const ROUTES:Routes=[
    {path:'', component:AcessoComponent},
    { path: "home", component: HomeComponent, canActivate:[AutenticacaoGuard]},
    { path: "profile", component: ProfileComponent, canActivate:[AutenticacaoGuard]}



]
```

Profile.ts

```
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

home.ts

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('publicacoes') public publicacoes:any
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }



  public atualizarTimeLine(){
    this.publicacoes.atualizarTimeLine()
  }
}
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, Create a component in case a user enter a random path and call it `PageNotFound`,

Secondly, Since angular start matching the entered route from top to down so the order of `ROUTES` array matters,

Finally: Consider changing your `ROUTE` array to:

```
export const ROUTES:Routes = [
  { path: "home", component: HomeComponent, canActivate:[AutenticacaoGuard]},
  { path: "profile", component: ProfileComponent, canActivate[AutenticacaoGuard]},
  { path: '',   redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
];
```

As well as i recommend you using [Lazy Loading](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules)

Comment: the problem is that when the user is authenticated and does the refresh (path:'') it should be redirect to home, but if the user isnt authenticated he should be redirected to accessoComponent (where I have to login form)

Comment: I did what you said, but when I wrote something like http://localhost:4200/jhgdkjshadl it redirects me to PageNotFoundComponent and after a few seconds it redirects me automatically to home component again and I dont know why